# Creating SelectionBorder: Bit in the face by decimal rounding?

Tags: wpf, double

I am currently implementing a class called SelectionBorder in WPF. It's derived from the Shape class.

It basically looks like this:

```
public class SelectionBorder : Shape
{
   public Point StartPoint {get; set;}
   public PointCollection Points {get; set;}

   public double StrokeLength {get; set;}

   protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry{
       get{
           //Magic!
       }
   }

}
```

The StartPoint and Points properties determine the corners of the border. The border is a typical stroked line border (one black stroke, one invisible stroke like that: - - - -)

The problem that I have now is that since the corner points are freely choosable it's pretty common that the count of strokes (meaning black and invisible strokes) is not even (in fact not even an integer) and therefore the first stroke looks longer than the others (visible in the picture). This maybe doesn't seem to be a big deal but I later want to animate the border so that the strokes circle round the content. When doing this animation the tiny flaw in the static view becomes clearly visible and in my opinion is highly disturbing.

[alt text http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/2874/selectionborder.png](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/2874/selectionborder.png)

The problem is that I tried to determine a StrokeLength that gets as close to the original StrokeLength as possible and creates an even number of strokes. However the problem I've run into is that WPF (obviously) can't display the whole precision of a double decimal StrokeLength and therefore the resulting stroke number is uneven once again.

Is there any workaround for this problem? Do you probably have another solution for my problem?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I retested and reviewed the code after a little break for fitness today and after all it happens only on very big StrokeLengths. I plan to use StrokeLengths of 2 where the little animation jumping does matter much less than I originally thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a way that makes it way easier to create such an animated SelectionBorder.

Instead of creating the animation by moving an self-created AnimationPoint through animation I just animated the StrokeDashOffset property natively provided by the Shape class and setting the StrokeDashArray to define the StrokeLength.

It would look like this in XAML:

```
<namespace:SelectionBorder StrokeDashArray="2" AnimationDuration="0:0:1" Stroke="Black" />
```

The class looks like this:

```
public class SelectionBorder : Shape
{
    private DoubleAnimation m_Animation;
    private bool m_AnimationStarted;

    public SelectionBorder()
    {
        IsVisibleChanged += OnIsVisibleChanged;
    }

    protected void OnIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            StartAnimation();
        }
        else
        {
            StopAnimation();
        }
    }

    public void StartAnimation()
    {
        if (m_AnimationStarted)
            return;

        if (m_Animation == null)
        {
            m_Animation = CreateAnimation();
        }

        BeginAnimation(StrokeDashOffsetProperty, m_Animation);
        m_AnimationStarted = true;
    }

    protected virtual DoubleAnimation CreateAnimation()
    {
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        animation.From = 0;
        if (StrokeDashArray.Count == 0)
            animation.To = 4;
        else
            animation.To = StrokeDashArray.First() * 2;
        animation.Duration = AnimationDuration;
        animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        return animation;
    }

    public void StopAnimation()
    {
        if (m_AnimationStarted)
        {
            BeginAnimation(StrokeDashOffsetProperty, null);
            m_AnimationStarted = false;
        }
    }

    #region Dependency Properties

    public Duration AnimationDuration
    {
        get { return (Duration)GetValue(AnimationDurationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnimationDurationProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimationDurationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AnimationDuration", typeof(Duration), typeof(SelectionBorder), new UIPropertyMetadata(new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))));


    #endregion Dependency Properties

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            double width = (double.IsNaN(Width)) ? ((Panel)Parent).ActualWidth : Width;
            double height = (double.IsNaN(Height)) ? ((Panel)Parent).ActualHeight : Height;

            RectangleGeometry geometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));

            return geometry;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make more than one corner "un-matched" in that regard. For example, instead of having one point be the "source" and "destination" of the animated dashes, you could pick 2 points. One would be the "source", dashes appearing to march away from it in 2 directions, and another point be the "destination", where dashes converge and disappear.

GIMP, for example, animates selection dashed lines in this way and seems to pick a point closest to the lower-left for the "source" and a point closest to the upper-right for the "destination".

You could come up with some other scheme, as well.

Just remember that while it may look disturbing to you, most users will not care.

Comment: You where right I maybe was a bit to picky. The advice with 2 starting points is also pretty good. Thanks!